# Using AT TIME ZONE to get current time in specified time zone

Tags: sql-server, timezone

I am trying to use the new [AT TIME ZONE syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt612795.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) in SQL Server 2016 and Azure SQL. I'm just trying to get the current time in London as a `datetime`, adjusted for daylight saving. At the time of running all of the commands below, the time in London was 3.27am.

The first step is to get a `datetimeoffset`, which I can successfully do as follows:

```
DECLARE @dto datetimeoffset
SET @dto = (SELECT GETUTCDATE() AT TIME ZONE 'GMT Standard Time')
SELECT @dto
```

This returns a value as I would expect:

```
2016-04-04 02:27:54.0200000 +01:00
```

Next, I want to convert that to a `datetime`, which is what my applications expect. I've tried three different approaches, none of which give me the result I'm looking for:

```
SELECT SWITCHOFFSET(@dto,'+00:00')
-- Returns 2016-04-04 01:27:54.0200000 +00:00

SELECT CONVERT(datetime, @dto)
-- Returns 2016-04-04 02:27:54.020

SELECT CONVERT(datetime2, @dto)
-- Returns 2016-04-04 02:27:54.0200000
```

I feel like I'm missing something obvious - is there an easy way to take a `datetimeoffset` and return just the date/time part at that offset?

Comment: Define "don't work". The two convert statements appear to be doing the right thing to me… If you're trying to get it to return 03:27, why not use the London TZ instead of "GMT Standard time" when you set @dto?

Comment: Perhaps "don't work" isn't quite right, and I'll adjust the question to change the wording - but I'd like to have some way to get back a datetime with a value of 03:27. There doesn't appear to be a 'London' time zone - GMT Standard Time is the time zone that London is in AFAIK.

Comment: I don't have a SQL 2016 instance installed, so I can't confirm your behavior. I did look at the Windows Registry at TZ info and it looks like GMT does indeed observe DST. One thing I noticed in your code though is that you called `getUTCdate()` which I'd expect to be the same everywhere (since it's Universal ant all). To test this, try three things 1) `SELECT GETUTCDATE() AT TIME ZONE 'GMT Daylight Time'` 2) `SELECT GETUTCDATE() AT TIME ZONE 'Tokyo Standard Time'` 3) `SELECT GETDATE() AT TIME ZONE 'GMT Standard Time'`

Comment: I'm actually doing this on Azure SQL, but I believe the behaviour will be the same on SQL 2016.

Comment: The results are: (1) - `Msg 9820, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The time zone parameter 'GMT Daylight Time' provided to AT TIME ZONE clause is invalid.`; (2) - `SELECT GETUTCDATE() AT TIME ZONE 'Tokyo Standard Time'`; (3) `2016-04-04 06:00:25.583 +01:00`. (The time that I ran this was 7am in London.)

Comment: How certain are you that the query was *actually* run at 3:27am and not 2:27am? The output of 2016-04-04 02:27:54.0200000 +01:00 is what I'd expect if it were run at 2:27am, especially given the SWITCHOFFSET part. Everything in your post is consistent with the query being run at 2:27am, basically. (Try a few different time zones, and see what happens - I suspect you'll see both the time *and* the offset changing, indicating that it's a local time to start with.)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The first line of your code contains the fault:

```
SELECT GETUTCDATE() AT TIME ZONE 'GMT Standard Time'
```

`GETUTCDATE()` returns a `datetime`, which has no time zone offset information.  Thus as described in [the MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt612795.aspx):

> If *inputdate* is provided without offset information, the function applies the offset of the time zone assuming that *inputdate* value is provided in the target time zone.

So, even though you retrieved the UTC time, you erroneously asserted that the value was in London time (which is UTC+1 for daylight saving time at this date).

The easiest way to handle this is to just fetch the UTC time as a `datetimeoffset` to begin with.

```
SELECT SYSDATETIMEOFFSET() AT TIME ZONE 'GMT Standard Time'
```

This invokes the *conversion* functionality of `AT TIME ZONE`, which in the docs states:

> If *inputdate* is provided as a *datetimeoffset* value, then `AT TIME ZONE` clause converts it into the target time zone using time zone conversion rules.

Consider that if your data actually comes from a `datetime` field somewhere, you might need to use *both* parts of the functionality, like this:

```
SELECT mydatetimefield AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'GMT Standard Time'
```

The first call to `AT TIME ZONE` asserts the value is in UTC, giving a `datetimeoffset` to the second call, which converts it to London time.

The output of any of these is a `datetimeoffset`, which you can cast or convert to a `datetime` or `datetime2` exactly as you showed in your original question.  (Don't use `switchoffset` for this.)

Also, the Windows time zone identifier for London is always `"GMT Standard Time"`.  It is inclusive of both Greenwich Mean Time and British Summer Time, with the appropriate transitions between them.  Do not try change it to `"GMT Daylight Time"` - that identifier doesn't exist.  This is also covered in [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info), in the section on Windows time zones.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to achieve exactly what I wanted using `SELECT CONVERT(datetime, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET() AT TIME ZONE 'GMT Standard Time')`. Thanks for the great explanation too.

Answer (score 7):

Since I was unable to find this anywhere else I thought I'd share. You can get the offset in minutes by using datepart (tz) with AT TIME ZONE.

```
datepart(tz,UTC_Date AT TIME ZONE 'Central Standard Time')

select dateadd(MINUTE,datepart(tz,cast('2018-07-02 17:54:41.537' as datetime) AT Time Zone 'Central Standard Time'),'2018-07-02 17:54:41.537') as CentralTime
```

returns

```
CentralTime
2018-07-02 12:54:41.537
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you only store this as a string and qualify that it is a local time representation, otherwise the time SQL Server stores internally would be the wrong actual/physical time, if the server time is correct, but just not in the same time zone.  It is why you cannot use convert to represent the same because you are actually changing the datetime value from the real time of occurrence and not just re-representing it i.e. Datetime is always stored as UTC, but entered and displayed in the timezone of the server, so if you enter a local time in a datetime field, the server interprets that time as the time in the server time zone and not the actual time of the event, which results in stored time navigation/deviation if the local time is not the same as the server>  Should you then feed the same data to other systems in different time zones, they will have incorrect data and it can get messy.  Store the right value in the datetime field and display it as you wish as a string.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's important to note that in principle UTC and GMT are the same thing and the terms are often interchangeable.  GMT used to be the global standard, UTC is based on it with some extra definitions.  But both are essentially the same and don't change based on DST changes etc.
https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenwich_Mean_Time

But, for some reason the SQL Server time zone called 'GMT Standard Time' actually means 'London Local Time' as it does change based on DST in London.  It is not the same as true GMT.