# Format Date based on the timezone i'm given in SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, timezone

I want to get the formatted date based on the timezone:

```
SELECT GETUTCDATE() AT TIME ZONE 'India Standard Time'
```

Functions like this, but the result is using this format:

```
2019-07-08 06:00:27.370 +05:30
```

Comment: What format/output do you actually want to see?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i want to see in a dd-MMM-yyyy format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try feeding the output of the `AT TIME ZONE` expression into `FORMAT`:

```
SELECT
    FORMAT(GETUTCDATE() AT TIME ZONE 'India Standard Time', 'dd-MMM-yyyy');
```

This outputs:

```
08-Jul-2019
```

If you also want to see the time component, then use the following mask with `FORMAT`:

```
dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss
```

Comment: Sure, it results the answer , but i have a question

Comment: i use this code 'SELECT
    FORMAT(GETDATE() AT TIME ZONE 'India Standard Time', 'dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss');' and it result the answer like this **08-Jul-2019 11:52:41**  and i have change the **Timezone** to **Pacific Standard Time** then also it shows the result **08-Jul-2019 11:52:41**  same as above why this happens?

Comment: @DhanilDinesan The follow up you are asking seems like a new question to me, in a different time zone.  Not sure what you want me to say.

Comment: I just want to know why its showing the same result. If you can help me with that it will be very helpful for me

Comment: I could speculate and say that perhaps your SQL Server's default timezone is set to Pacific Standard Time.

Comment: No my servers default Timezone is in India StandardTime, I think that will be the reason. Thank you very much

Comment: if you think this question is relevant please give upvote for this question

Comment: It happens because you are *asserting* that the `datetime` values are in the time zone specified.  You are not *converting* them.  See the answer I marked as duplicate for details.

Comment: @MattJohnson I get your point, but my assumption here was that the OP's requirement was one of presentation only.

Comment: Agreed. There's some conflation between formatting and time zone in the question for sure.  [Here is the question I originally marked as duplicate, which address the time zone portion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36393742/using-at-time-zone-to-get-current-time-in-specified-time-zone).

Answer (score 1):

You can cast the dates as Datetime-offset:

```
SELECT CAST(GETUTCDATE() AT TIME ZONE 'India Standard Time' AS datetimeoffset(0))
SELECT CAST(GETUTCDATE() AT TIME ZONE 'Pacific Standard Time' AS datetimeoffset(0))
```